# Getting Id of enum which I have bound to a dropdown list

Tags: c#

I have set of enums bound to a dropdown list.

```
((DropDownList)control).DataSource = DefaultSync;
((DropDownList)control).DataBind();
```

Here Defaultsync is the list which contains 2 enums.

```
List<MyEnum> DefaultSync=(List<SyncRequestTypeEnum>)(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SyncRequestTypeEnum)).Cast<SyncRequestTypeEnum>().Except(new SyncRequestTypeEnum[] { SyncRequestTypeEnum.ProjectLevel })).ToList();
```

Now I wanted to get the id of the enum based on the user selection of the dropdownlist.
I used the following code but it is giving an error as the list does not contain value for it.

```
public int EnumID
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(ddlselection.Selectedvalue);
    }
    set
    {
        ddlselection.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(value);
    } 
}
```

Can someone help on this?

Error is :
'ddlselection has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `SelectedValue` property you need to specify which property of your data item is the value property and which one is the displayed text. I would suggest changing your code to something like this:

```
var list = control as DropDownList;
list.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SyncRequestTypeEnum))
    .Cast<SyncRequestTypeEnum>()
    .Except(/*..*/)
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<SyncRequestTypeEnum, string>(x, x.ToString())
    .ToList();
list.DataValueField = "Key";
list.DataTextField = "Value";
list.DataBind();
```

And your property should work fine.

Another example and more detailed explanation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).